# How to play a live RTSP video in Videoview Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, vlc, rtsp

Can anyone please help me to play a live rtsp video in android. The rtsp link was got by using my VLC player.
When I run the app I got the following error

Couldn't open rtsp:---------:8554/stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://--------:8554/stream
2019-10-12 12:39:16.677 5958-5970/example.com.rtspexample 
W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (701, 0)

Thanks,

Comment: I have rtsp link ( got from VLC player using USB camera) .I need to play that video in my android application

Comment: it would be great if you can also edit your question to reflect what have you tried till so far, to solve your problem, so that we can better analyze it :)